# How to use {\ in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am using AutoHotKey to help me in my writing

So instead of writing `{\color{red}`  I will just push one key and AutoHotKey will do the writing of the whole thing

P.S. I am repeating these letters hundreds of times in my paper.

When I used it in my AutoHotKey file like this

```
^4::Send {\color{red}
```

which does nothing, nothing was written in my paper

and when i use this

```
^4::{\color{red}
```

I get this error when i load the AutoHotKey file

```
---------------------------
My.ahk
---------------------------
Error at line 14.

Line Text: {\color{red}
Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.

The script was not reloaded; the old version will remain in effect.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Any idea how to get it wok?

Comment: See the `Send` [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Send command or Hotstrings are used in their default
(non-raw) mode, characters such as {}^!+# have special meaning.
To use them literally in these cases, enclose them in
braces:

```
^4::Send {{}\color{{}red{}}
```

or use the [raw mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Raw)

```
^4::SendRaw {\color{red}
```

or the **[Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Text) (recommended)**:

```
^4::Send {Text}{\color{red}
```

See also [Escape Sequences](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/EscapeChar.htm)

Comment: i tried them all but still getting this error ---------------------------
My.ahk
---------------------------
Error:  Unexpected "}"

 Line#
 015: SetKeyDelay,-1
 015: Send,{Blind}{} DownR}
 015: Return
 015: SetKeyDelay,-1
 015: Send,{Blind}{} Up}
 015: Return
 016: Return
---> 018: }
 019: Exit
 020: Exit
 020: Exit

The script was not reloaded; the old version will remain in effect.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: The error is caused on another line. Try the above codes in a script with no other code and close all other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on AHKv2, you need to use SendRaw and wrap the input in quotes:

```
^4::SendRaw "{\color{red}}"
```

I'd recommend using a [hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotstrings.htm) instead:

```
:T:;red::{\color{red}
```